# Is exposing a bind shell to tor dangerous?

Tags: tor, python

I have a bind shell written in python:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", "710"))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(f"[*] Connection established from {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}") 

while True:
        command = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if command.strip() == 'exit':
            conn.close()
            break
        output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        conn.send(output.encode())
```

and I am exposing it to tor by listing the port as a tor hidden service in torrc, only I know the onion address, is this safe?

Comment: *"is this safe"* - Safe against what? Against accessing this exposed service by others? This would basically be asking if the knowledge of the onion address counts as strong authentication and your actual code does not matter. Or what exactly you ask about?

Answer (score 1):

Since tor is just a network, you are essentially asking if having a hidden port is enough to safeguard you.

And no, there is nothing in tor (or the internet) that prevents you from just trying all addresses. (In tor it does take a tad more effort… but not much).

Meaning that your odd port number is your sole protection.

Which is registered in the IANA database as:

> entrust-ash   710 tcp Entrust Administration Service Handler

> entrust-ash   710 udp Entrust Administration Service Handler

Since plenty of scanners try all privileged ports, your little secret won’t stay a secret… it’s just a matter of time.

Why don’t you just use the software made to do this; ssh. It can even be setup so it requires you to use private keys… which are superior to passwords.

Finally, is this strategy of yours smart?  No, it’s just security by obscurity… nothing more.

Comment: A tad more effort... there are 2^280 V3 addresses, that's a bit more than a tad :)

Comment: you are assuming you have to go through each address 1 by 1. which isn't really the case...  there are ways to reduce this space by using other resources... if you lack said resources... yes that's about the size. but its not a problem either for the ipv6 space either... why would it be for tor's space?

Comment: Thanks. What are the other resources you mentioned?

Comment: I can’t go into full details, due to restrictions.  But just consider that the people that actually route the data. Can also see some parts of it.  And there are many actors on TOR….

Comment: Ok, but that is not "trying all addresses"

Comment: It’s trying all active addresses… it’s functionally the same. Without being absolutely the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. Great technique! I hope the full details become public at some point, would make a great BlackHat talk or something